# How to generate OpenApi Client SDK project in .Net Core

Tags: c#, openapi, webapi

Our customer has given us a swagger link for all of their API end-points. We have a .Net Core project using VS 2022 and .Net 6.
Now we want to generate an OpenAPI client project to our same .Net Core solutions so that we will be calling the client's API end-point via the OpenAPI project.

The Steps I followed are:

- I downloaded the swagger json file from customer end point.
- I followed [this document](https://medium.com/@no0law1/generate-client-sdk-for-net-core-using-open-api-no0law1-4767fa86a17f)

As mentioned in that document, first, I installed Open API using this command

`npm install @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli -g`

Then, when I execute OpenAPI Generator CLI to generate our SDK with this command, I am getting the error **'Java' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

`openapi-generator generate -i swagger.json -g csharp-netcore -o Api.Client.Sdk --additional-properties packageName=Api.Client.Sdk`

Comment: OpenAPI isn't a library or custom protocol. It's a common way of specifying HTTP API endpoints and DTOs. You don't need to create anything special to call the HTTP APIs, just use HttpClient. A generator can be used to generate the DTOs for you from the OpenAPI link but is *not* necessary

Comment: Besides, if you want to generate C# classes, you need a C# generator, not Javascript

Comment: Check the [ASP.NET Core docs on OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0). Swashbuckle is used to create Web API projects with an OpenAPI schema. To generate client code from an existing schema you can use NSwag, either through the [dotnet api tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0), or [tools, APIs based on NSwag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#code-generation)

Comment: He's asking about openapi-generator not OpenAPI. The openapi-generator IS a C# generator, along with a hundred other languages and frameworks. Swashbuckle is a C# specific generator. The openapi-generator REQUIRES Java to be installed and available on the path.

Comment: You can use OpenAPI Generator Docker CLI without installing Java: https://hub.docker.com/r/openapitools/openapi-generator-cli

Answer (score 5):

You should probably start from the [ASP.NET Core docs on OpenAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-6.0), to understand what OpenAPI is and what the various libraries do. OpenAPI isn't a library or custom protocol. It's a common way of specifying HTTP API endpoints and DTOs. You don't need to create anything special to call the HTTP APIs, just use HttpClient. A generator can be used to generate the DTOs for you from the OpenAPI link but is not necessary.

Swashbuckle is just one library that can be used to create Web API projects that provide an OpenAPI schema. It does this by generating a `swagger.json` document from your application's controllers and DTOs. You could create that document by hand if you wanted, but Swashbuckle is certainly easier to use.

You can use libraries like NSwag to generate boilerplate client code from an OpenAPI schema. One way is through the [dotnet api tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which generates a C# client and objects from a Swagger document.

You can install the tool with

```
dotnet tool install -g Microsoft.dotnet-openapi
```

And use it with `dotnet openapi add url ....` to configure your project to generate C# code at build time.

Let's say you create an empty console application with

```
dotnet new console
```

You can add generate a client based on the `https://petstore3.swagger.io/` schema with

```
dotnet openapi add url https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json --help
```

This will add the `NSwag.ApiDescription.Client` NuGet package to the applition and an `OpenApiReference` tag pointing to the Schema document. This way the client can be refreshed when the schema changes.

The `csproj` file will look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.ApiDescription.Client" Version="13.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <OpenApiReference Include="openapi.json" SourceUrl="https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3/openapi.json" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The tool will also generate an `openapiClient` file and class inside the `obj` folder, which makes it available to the rest of the application. The client can now be used in Program.cs:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

var http = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://petstore3.swagger.io/") };

var client = new openapitest.openapiClient(http);
var results = await client.GetInventoryAsync();

Console.WriteLine(results);
```

The tool itself uses the [NSwag library for code generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-nswag?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#code-generation). There are other tools and applications that can generate C# code from an OpenAPI document.

Comment: Thank you, @Panagiotis Kanavos. Just to clarify about my question is, We have a .Net Core project and we want to add a **Open Api Client Project (generated from Swagger url)** in the same Solution, so that, we can call the Api end point **VIA** this Open Api Client project. When we generate this Client Project from swagger link, which is given by customer, the Client project should add **Api, Client, docs, and Model folder.** So, from our .Net Core app, we will be invoke the Client Api method, which eventually hit the actual API endpoint. Any idea how can we create a Client project ?

Comment: That's what this answer shows. There's no "via" or "Open API Client project". Just generated classes. You can generate those in any project you want. If you want those to be in a separate project, execute `dotent openapi` in that project's folder

Comment: I think we are very close. I'm getting it. I followed this command to generate the classes/project however I am getting **Java is not recocnized.** Do I need to install Java in my system ? I ran this command `openapi-generator-cli generate -i petstore.yaml -g aspnetcore -o PetStore.Web --package-name PetStore.Web`  I followed [this link to get the Command](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2022/02/06/using-openapi-generator-to-scaffold-apis-and-api-clients/) Thanks for your help

Comment: I explained in the question's comments *and* this question that you don't need that tool at all. Did you try what I posted?

Comment: The last step was rather tricky. For the openAPI doc I tried (with Hubspot API, well-used at this point) it weirdly has generated the same client over and over again in the generated code. One client for each path and method. I guess it's something peculiar about their version of OpenAPI.

Comment: If you have trouble generating a proxy for a specific service you should make this explicit in the question itself. As it stands, the question essentially asks what tool to use for proxy generation in .NET. The answer is "not that one". It's quite possible that Hubspot uses a single OpenAPI document to describe all its serviced. Update the question to describe the *actual* problem and what you tried

Comment: He's looking to use the community supported OpenAPI Generator not OpenAPI or Swagger or Swashbuckle. The former requires Java runtime. That's the issue he's experiencing.

Comment: I'd like to see an option that can generate from the ASP.NET assembly instead of a swagger.json file already hosted somewhere on the web. My workflow is to build the client after the server, and reference the freshly built assembly to generate the Open API document. I use the nswag tooling for this now, but looking for something more intrinsic to .NET (i.e. Swashbuckle, dotnet cli)